# Flutter StreamBuilder return no data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to call the user first name in my drawer.

I already follow the suggestions in other question to use connection state, I use it already, but the result still null. The result when I try to call my drawer is 'Oops, there is no data'

Can someone show me which part is not correct? Really appreciate your help.

DatabaseService:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  final String taskId;

  DatabaseService({this.uid, this.taskId});

  //collection reference
  CollectionReference userCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('user');

  //get user data stream
  Stream<UserData> get userData {
    return userCollection.document(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }

  //user data from snapshot
  UserData _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserData(fName: snapshot.data['first_name']);
  }

} // DatabaseService
```

Drawer:

```
class DrawerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          UserData userData = snapshot.data;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Drawer(...);
              default:
                return Drawer(
              child: Center(child: Text(userData.fName)), //Try to call the data here
            );
            }
          } else {
            return Drawer(
              child: Center(child: Text('Oops, there is no data')),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Data in Firebase:
[image: firestore]

Comment: Please check in firebase whether you have data there,and your request query

Comment: the data is already there, I add the screenshot

Comment: I am little confused about your code, sorry if I am getting wrong because I hadn't to chance to try. You return below lines in future:`return UserData(fName: snapshot.data['first_name']);` Then you call it as: `userData.fName` again so can you try to print userData to see please?

Comment: @Lunedor I have 2 properties of userData, one in class DatabaseService, the other one in class DrawerWidget. In DatabaseService, userData contains of Stream. In DrawerWidget, it contains the snapshot. When I print DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData, it return Instance of '_MapStream<DocumentSnapshot, UserData>'. When I print userData in DrawerWidget, it return null.